# Disappeared graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, bios, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo T520 with two graphics cards, an nVidia quadro and an intel graphics card. I'm running a Ubuntu and Windows 7 dual boot.

I can no longer find any trace of my intel graphics card. In my linux boot:

```
> lspci | grep VGA
> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GF106 [Quadro 2000M] (rev a1)
```

In Windows in control panel > display- >advanced settings, I only see the NVIDIA Quadro 2000M.

In the BIOS there is no mention of the intel graphics card, no where I can find to try and turn it on or off.

I thought I was going crazy, but then I found a post I made on ask ubuntu I made 3 months ago where I listed the output of lspci on this same machine:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GF106 [Quadro 2000M] (rev a1)
```

What is going on? How could my intel graphics card have been disabled or turned off somehow without my knowledge? I've been in the BIOS 3 times now, each time convinced the last time I must have missed something, but I always find nothing. Am I missing something there? Could a thief have opened my computer and stolen my graphics card?

Comment: Have you tried opening the case and seeing if it's still there? :)

Comment: Did you switch to your nVIDIA card using Optimus? It's an hardware switch.

Comment: How would one flip this hardware switch?